# how to link two table with a auto incrimented id in one table?

Tags: php, mysql

if i have a table like this

```
tbl_attributes
---------------
id_attrib (auto incremented, primary key)
col1
col2
```

and another table

```
tbl_weight
--------------
id_attrib *(not primary key)*
field
```

when it comes time to insert values into the table tbl_attributes as i insert values for col1 and col2 the id_attrib is auto incremented. how can i insert that same auto incremented value of id_attribute into the field id_attrib in the table tbl_weight . the reason im doing this is because
i am looking for specific values being entered into tbl_attributes and once the value im looking for has been inserted into tbl_attributes then more information related to that will be entered into tbl_weight.

otherwise if i combined the tables which would look like

```
tbl_attributes
----------------
id_attrib
col1
col2
field (from tbl_weight table)
```

the field column would contain alot of empty data and would only contain data when something is met and i dont want to do it like that.

so maybe getting the current auto_increment to be used for tbl_attributes and insert that value. I was thinking of using innodb format but i am new to that world and things might get messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_attributes VALUES(...)";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if ($res) {
  $last_autoincrement_id = mysql_insert_id();
  // add code here
  }
```

Manual: [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

> Retrieves the ID generated for an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous
>   query (usually INSERT).

Now you can use that ID for another INSERT query (`tbl_weight`).

Example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_weight VALUES('$last_autoincrement_id', ...)";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: Don't forget to check `mysql_query()` result.

Comment: i never check for the results of the query since i dont see a purpose. whats the purpose of it? thnx

Comment: Purpose of checking result? To get if request was successful? E.g. `mysql_query('BAD MYSQL REQUEST')`... This will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

After inserting into the first auto increment table, call the php function `mysql_insert_id()`.  This will return the auto increment id from the previous insert, which you can use in your subsequent insert.  The native MySQL function called by the PHP function is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_attributes (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2');");

if ($result)
{
   // Get the auto increment id from the first INSERT
   $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
   // And use it in the second INSERT
   $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_weight (id_attrib, field) VALUES ($last_id, 'fieldval');");
}
else // first insert failed
```

[Official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) on `mysql_insert_id()`